# What is an Astral Node?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-thaumcraft

I'm still confused on how to do more advanced things with nodes, but I came across an Astral Node, and I can't find info about it anywhere. Also, nothing new was learned when I scanned it, unlike the other kinds of nodes. Does anyone know anything about them?

Answer (score 1):

#### Astral nodes react to the light level

The [Thaumcraft 5 wiki](http://thaumcraft-5.wikia.com/wiki/Auras_and_Nodes#Types) states:

> - Astral Node - the Astral Node is a rare Node type that replenishes the respective Aura it is attuned to depending on the amount of light it is exposed to, with higher levels of light correlating with faster output of aspects into the Aura.

While the above was written for TC5, reddit user [/u/Xirema notes:](https://www.reddit.com/r/Thaumcraft/comments/406318/tc5_thaumcraft_510_released/cysjdk9?context=10000)

> Those were in the previous versions. They work exactly as expected: the greater the light level near the node, the more aura they put out.

Answer (score -2):

The greater the amount of light, the faster the astral node recharges the aura.